# Checking if the message.author has a certain role

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that can only be used by people with a certain role. Currently I'm using:

```
if discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, name="Admin").name == "Admin":
    #do stuff here
```

it works, but if the user doesn't have that role a

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

error is thrown. Is there any native discord.py function that could be used?

I'm not keen on trying to catch the problem with exceptions

`has_roles()` no longer seems to exist

Comment: "*`has_roles()` no longer seems to exist*" - Are you sure about that? What have you tried?

Comment: Well I ran a search under the api https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html and no it didn't seem to @Dominik

Comment: Just to make sure: It still exists in the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands.has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very helpful here. Apparently `get` sometimes returns `None`.

```
role = discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, name="Admin")
if role is not None and role.name == "Admin":
    #do stuff here
```

Answer (score 2):

**loa_in_** provided a good method, but you can also check it differently.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin") # Get the role
    if role in ctx.author.roles: # Check if the author has the role
        await ctx.send("You can do this")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have the `Admin` role.")
```

- You can also insert the `id` instead of the name, so you do not have to change the code every time the role name changes.